# How to setup eclipse for the first time for C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-c++, eclipse-plugin

i have Visual C++ installed on my system. I downloaded eclipse-cpp-indigo-SR1-incubation-win32. I followed the following steps to create a new C++ project:

```
File-->> New -->> C++ Project-->> Gave it a (name) -->> Hello World C++ Project-->> Finish
```

Then I entered this example program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

This code was pre-written.

I clicked the green (run) button, but this gave me the error message: "launch failed: binary not found".

As mentioned in comments, I clicked hammer (build) button, and this gave the error message : "a program file was not specified in the build configuration"

Can anybody troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select the source file, and press "hammer" (build) icon first. And then the green one.

Comment: hmmm, now it says "a program file was not specified in the build configuration"

Comment: I'm not sure what this is. Does it compile ok? To be able to compile, you need to tell eclipse what to compile, which you can do by activating editor window that contains some source belonging to that project. If it compiled fine, then probably your "launch configuration" has no binary specified. Just press down arrow next to "run" icon, select run configurations, select your configuration and click "search project" button while in "main" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Control (Command for macs) + b, Control (Command) + r

Or just Control (Command) + Shift + r

With c++ you have to build it (control + b) so it compiles to something the computer can run, before you run it.

Answer (score 0):

I just download the eclipse and follow you step by step. I press the "hammer" and then "green run". It works. Give it another try.:)

Comment: :( it's not going that way in my case :(

Comment: it builds binary, n then tells binary not found :O . where does the F****** binary goes to.

Answer (score 0):

My friend had a very, very similar problem. I fixed it by reinstalling Visual C++ but it could be fixed by just reinstalling eclipse. What version of Windows are you using?